# Manually sending a post in PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form that will be validated client side before being submitted via an ajax request to the server for server-side validation. Should the validation fail server side then a postback will need to be made containing all the error messages. Is there some way I can do this?

For example:

```
if ((!empty($nameError) && (!empty($emailError)) {

    $_POST['nameError'] = $nameError;
    $_POST['emailError'] = $emailError;
    // send postback with values
}
else {

    echo 'No errors';
}
```

UPDATE ------------------------------------------------

Here is the javascript that handles the submission of the form:

```
$(".button").click(function() {

            $(".error").hide();

            var name = $(":input.name").val();
            if ((name == "") || (name.length < 4)){

                $("label#nameErr").show();
                $(":input.name").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var email = $(":input.email").val();
            if (email == "") {

                $("label#emailErr").show();
                $(":input.email").focus();
                return false;
            }


            var phone = $(":input.phone").val();
            if (phone == "") {

                $("label#phoneErr").show();
                $(":input.phone").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var comment = $.trim($("#comments").val());
            if ((!comment) || (comment.length > 100)) {

                $("label#commentErr").show();
                $("#comments").focus();
                alert("hello");
                return false;
            }

            var info = 'name:' + name + '&email:' + email + '&phone:' + phone + '&comment:' + comment;
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>';
            alert(info);

            jQuery.ajax({

                type:"post",
                dataType:"json",
                url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                data: {action: 'submit_data', info: info},
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.type == "success") {

                        alert("success");
                    }
                    else {

                        alert("fail");
                    }
                }
            });

            $(":input").val('');
            return false;


        });
```

And here is the php function that the ajax posts to:

```
function submit_data() {

    $nameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $commentErr = "";
    $full = explode("&", $_POST["info"]);
    $fname = explode(":", $full[0]);
    $name = $fname[1];
    $femail = explode(":", $full[1]);
    $email = $femail[1];
    $fphone = explode(":", $full[2]);
    $phone = $fphone[1];
    $fcomment = explode(":", $full[3]);
    $comment = $fcomment[1];

    if ((empty($name)) || (strlen($name) < 4)){

        $nameErr = "Please enter a name";
    }
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {

        $nameErr = "Please ensure you have entered your name and surname";
    }


    if (empty($email)) {

        $emailErr = "Please enter an email address";
    }
    else if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) {

        $emailErr = "Please ensure you have entered a valid email address";
    }


    if (empty($phone)) {

        $phoneErr = "Please enter a phone number";
    }
    else if (!preg_match("/(?:\(?\+\d{2}\)?\s*)?\d+(?:[ -]*\d+)*$/",$phone)) {

        $phoneErr = "Please ensure you have entered a valid phone number";
    }


    if ((empty($nameErr)) && (empty($emailErr)) && (empty($phoneErr)) && (empty($commentErr))) {

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "John", "Change9", "plugindatadb");
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO data (Name, Email, Phone, Comment) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$comment')");
    }
    else {

        // display error messages
    }

    die();
}
```

Comment: If by postback you mean you want to redirect the page (or call it self again), then, NO you can't, cuz once you redirect the post will be gone. The question is, why you want to redirect back (or refresh) the page?

Comment: Do you maybe have any suggestions about how I could then get error messages to display on the page? I have tried echoing a javascript script that will set the error messages to show but no luck

Comment: use `$_SESSION['nameError']` instead .

Comment: So actually you don't need to refresh the page, you need to show the error message only. Is that correct?   The fact that you use AJAX is what preventing your echoing to work. Please share your ajax code and show us how you call the php page. **That part is responsible for displaying the error message, not the php part** PHP will only set the flag for you and maybe return back the error message text, but JAVASCRIPT is the one which will handle the process from there.

Comment: @Joraid posted the code. So once the error messages have been returned (say by a json_encode function) do I then trigger a javascript function to display the error messages?

Comment: yes, you need to show these by javascript code

Comment: The problem then is that because I am not able to echo any script due to the Ajax how will I be able to trigger the function?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will be in two parts:

Pseudo code:

**Part1: PHP**

```
if ($error) {
    $reply["status"]=false;
    $reply["message"]="Fail message"; //Here you have to put your own message, maybe use a variable from the validation you just did before this line: $reply["message"] = $fail_message.
}
else {    
    $reply["status"]=true;
    $reply["message"]="Success message"//$reply["message"] = $success_message;
}

echo json_encode($reply);//something like {"status":true, "message":"Success message"}
```

**Part2 AJAX:** modify you ajax response to this.

```
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status == true) {

                        alert("success: "+response.message);
                    }
                    else {

                        alert("fail: " + response.message);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use json ajax request. In case error exists show the error message. I generally put a flag for success or fail .

```
$message='';
if ((!empty($nameError) && (!empty($emailError)) {

     $errorArray=array();
    $errorArray['nameError'] = $nameError;
    $errorArray['emailError'] = $emailError;
    // send postback with values
}
else {

    $message='No errors';
}

echo json_encode(array(
"message"=>$message,
"errors"=>$errorArray
));
```